# Device Update for IoT : I am able to import the changes but not seeing Updates Available under 'Groups And Deployment' Tab, anyone can please help me

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I have configured the Device Update Agent into IoT Device. Imported multiple Updates via 'Import a new Update' Option but inside 'Groups and Deployment' Tab I am not seeing any new update.

Please see below links for more details

[image: New Import]

[image: New Update available count is 0]

Answer (score 0):

> using [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/configure-access-control-device-update?tabs=portal#configure-access-for-azure-device-update-service-principal-in-linked-iot-hub),[Ms-Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-simulator) I was able to Import a new Update in IoT Hub.

[image]

- Add the Access Control in IoT Hub

[image]

[image]

- Make sure that the IoT Hub Data Contributor role is listed under Role assignments after selecting Azure Device Update.

[image]

- Search for "Azure Device Update" using the User, Group, or Service Principal selection.

[image]

[image]

- Choose Devices in the left pane. Choose Add Device next.

[image]

- Choose Add Module Identity, then type a name for the module under Module Identity Name.

[image]

[image]

- At the same level as the model Id and version tags in the twin file, add a new Device Update tag value as follows:

```
"tags": {
    "ADUGroup": "DU-simulator-tutorial"
},
```

[image]

- Install and configure the Device [Update agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmAjn.png)

[image]

- Select Upload in your container, then navigate to the files you got for the requirements. Select [Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPkYq.png) after choosing the adu-update-image-raspberrypi3.swu and TutorialImportManifest_Sim.importmanifest.json files.

[image]

- After click on check the status in **Groups and Deployments**.

[image]

Comment: If have questions related to your question(or) answer. Please ask in the comments

Comment: With Simulator I can able to deploy the changes and getting successful response for Image base & Package base both. For the actual Package deployment what we need to do any idea? did you updated existing package using Device Update ?

Comment: Hello @YogeshAmrutkar Do with  Simulator for                                                   [Package deployment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-configure-repo.md)

Comment: with Simulator I have already tired, it's working fine. Now I want to update actual existing package or deploy a totally new package into device from IoT Hub using Device Update. Any input on that ?

Comment: Hello @YogeshAmrutkar Will check any reference Doc available and update you

Comment: Any update ?, When I am trying to verify the Package Base update with OTA I am getting 'Failed to parse specified APT file' Error with code ADUC_ERC_UPDATE_CONTENT_HANDLER_PARSE_BAD_FORMAT

Comment: Hello, @YogeshAmrutkar found the related [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-simulator.md) and [trying](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-ubuntu-agent.md) to [implement](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/deploy-update.md) [it](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/create-update-group.md).

Answer (score 0):

Solution : In du-config.json whatever manufacture & model we use during DeviceAgent Configuration same we need to use inside .importmanifest.json file during import otherwise Import is successful but in Deployment Tab you won't see any new updates to Deploy